# linux_rename files in directory by prepending with timestamp using find command

Tags: linux, file, rename

I am trying to rename files in current directory by prepending timestamp value using find command like below

```
 find . -type f -exec mv {} $(date +%Y-%m-%d)_{} \;
```

But getting 'Can't move, no such file or directory error', but appending works well with below command, not sure what is the difference between two.

```
 find . -type f -exec mv {} {}.$(date +%Y-%m-%d) \;
```

Comment: `find` returns absolute paths, so basically you're trying to execute command like that: `mv /home/user/file 2021-10-11_/home/user/file`. The second argument is a not a valid path and that what the error shows.

Comment: This worked finally for me, "  find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv {} $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)_$(basename {})' \; "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} $(date +%Y-%m-%d)$(basename {}) \;
```